# repeat html within the same component

Tags: angular, ng-template

I am looking for a way to repeat the same markup on multiple spots in my component. I know I could just use a new component but im looking for something a little less serious.

**The html**

```
        <nav class="pages">
            <ul class="inline">
                <li 
                    *ngFor="let p of pages; let i = index;"
                    [ngClass]="{'active': page.current_page == i+1}"
                    (click)="onPageChange(i+1, $event)"
                >{{i+1}}</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Is there a way to use `ng-template` to repeat this same mark up in multiple places within the same component... Something like below

```
<div id="header"> <ng-template [innHTML]="#pages"></ng-template> </div>
<div id="content">...</div>
<div id="footer"> <ng-template [innHTML]="#pages"></ng-template> </div>

<ng-container #pages>
    <ul class="inline">
        <li *ngFor="let p of pages; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'active': page.current_page == i+1}" (click)="onPageChange(i+1, $event)">{{i+1}}</li>
    </ul>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can insert the content of an `ng-template` with `ng-container` Angular elements and the [ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) directive.

```
<div id="header">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="pages; context: { text: 'value1' }"></ng-container>
</div>
<div id="content">...</div>
<div id="footer">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="pages; context: { text: 'value2' }"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #pages let-value="text">
  <div>The value is {{value}}</div>
  <ul class="inline">
    <li *ngFor="let p of pages; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'active': page.current_page == i+1}" (click)="onPageChange(i+1, $event)">{{i+1}}</li>
  </ul>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: is there a way to pass a val in to `ng-template` from `ng-container`?

Comment: Yes, you can pass values in the `context` of the `ngTemplateOutlet`. I updated the answer to show that. You can also see it at work in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5rtxrn).

Comment: Worth noting that values accessible elsewhere in the component are equally accessible in your template, including for data binding, you don't have to pass them in. Values you pass in are read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Create a child component containing your html in it's template and use it as many times you need in your (parent) component, like so:

Child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-comp',
  template: `
    <nav class="pages">
        <ul class="inline">
            <li 
                *ngFor="let p of pages; let i = index;"
                [ngClass]="{'active': page.current_page == i+1}"
                (click)="onPageChange(i+1, $event)"
            >{{i+1}}</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child-comp.component.css']
})
export class ChildCompComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() pages;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onPageChange(index, event) {
  }

}
```

Parent Component:

```
<div id="header">
  <app-child-comp [pages]="pages"></app-child-comp>
</div>
<div id="content">...</div>
<div id="footer">
  <app-child-comp [pages]="pages"></app-child-comp>
</div>
```