# How can I reuse HTML in multiple places without an additional component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, vmware-clarity

I'm currently trying to i18n the menu to display the columns to show. I realized I can use the following to customize its text.

[image]

```
<clr-dg-column-toggle>
    <clr-dg-column-toggle-title>{{‘clr.dg.column.toggle.title’ | translate}}
    </clr-dg-column-toggle-title>
    <clr-dg-column-toggle-button clrType = “selectAll”>{{‘clr.dg.column.toggle.selectAll’ | translate}}
    </clr-dg-column-toggle-button>
</clr-dg-column-toggle>
```

However, we have over 50 grids and I would like to avoid copy pasting this into all of them. How can I avoid that? This would be so easy in React, but Angular just makes it really complicated.

At first, I just created a function that returns that HTML and called it from the template, but that doesn't work in AOT.

Next, I thought I could use a structural directive and just use

> `<clr-dg-column-toggle *myCustomDirective></clr-dg-column-toggle>`

But [structural directives](https://teropa.info/blog/2016/03/06/writing-an-angular-2-template-directive.html) don't seem to be used for dynamically generating HTML.

I suppose I could [dynamically create those components](https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d) but it seems like a lot of work to reuse some HTML. 
I also thought I could create another component, but I hate adding bloat to the DOM just to reuse HTML. Especially when DOM depth is the [first of 4 guidelines](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow#guidelines) you should be aware of to make your UI reflows perform better.

I currently am creating a directive on the grid itself that just hot swaps the text for translated text after the view has rendered by querying the DOM for `clr-dg-column-toggle-title/clr-dg-column-toggle-button`. Is there a better Angular way?

Comment: why don't you create a separate component? `<my-toggle-component title="title"></...>`

Comment: the idea of the presentation component is avoiding the same HTML [and styling] = what you need

Comment: @DDRamone Because I will have to copy/paste the HTML/CSS from Clarity? Not sure what you are saying,  also, please write a single comment whenever possible.

Comment: I would really like to understand better what you are trying to achieve. For me, it looks like you can create a component (that will be reused - way of angular) using inputs to provide your data that will be translated. This way you can inject the component anywhere you need.

Comment: @AndrewRadulescu I explained why in the question, it's HTML bloat, making the DOM slow. I also don't need input parameters. In React, you create another component but it doesn't make the DOM heavier/slower

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504584/1009922) could help you.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I don't think it can, I know about templateRefs, but there's no component passing it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question itself, but a different solution the the problem I actually faced. [Clarity](https://clarity.design/) will provide a different way to localize strings by having you override their translation service in app.module providers

```
providers: [{provide: ClrCommonStrings, useClass: MyCommonStringsService}]
```

See https://github.com/vmware/clarity/pull/3312

Answer (score 0):

To reuse HTML over multiple components without requiring a new component and still have it work in AOT, you can use [macro functions](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#macro-functions-and-macro-static-methods) in your templates.

In your simple case, you can export a  `const I18n_CLR_DG = "<clr-dg-column-toggle>...</>";` and just use use that within your template.

To avoid remembering to reference this in every template, you could create a macro function `createClrDatagrid(options)` that generates your HTML with an option to display the column selector depending on how much you'd need customize the HTML for the `<clr-datagrid>`.