# Localization support for Datagrid Hide/Show feature

Tags: vmware-clarity

Localization support for Datagrid with Hide/Show option

Our project supports localization. And we are using Datagrid in multiple pages with show/hide columns. We see that Select All and Show columns getting displayed in English irrespective of locale when clicked on show/hide icon.
Would like to know is this expected behavior?

ColumnName

Expected: Based on locale, strings to appear in respective language
Actual: Always appears in English

[DataGrid_Show/Hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOEHS.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reuse HTML in multiple places without an additional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813367/how-can-i-reuse-html-in-multiple-places-without-an-additional-component)

Answer (score 1):

Clarity originally supported localization for Datagrid Column Toggler through adding custom components as you see here https://clarity.design/documentation/datagrid/hide-show.

In Clarity v2+, that will go away and the locale will change the strings based on your commonStrings service. Depending what version you are running, you will need to decide which approach to use.